# UNIQUE constraint failed on Posting form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to post a simle form to create a user. but whenever i try to save the form data it always gives me UNIQUE constraint failed error even if i pass the new mobile number that does not exist on database.

**ERROR IS:** UNIQUE constraint failed: core_user.mobile_no

**models.py**

**Manager Class is:**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new user"""
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have an username")
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_staff_user(self, username, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(username, password, is_staff=True, **kwargs)
        return user

    def create_super_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(self, username=username, password=password, is_staff=True, is_super_user=True)
        return user
```

**Model class is:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_types = (
        ("staff", "Staff"),
        ("super_user", "Super User"),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can login
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff user
    is_super_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # super user
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = UserManager()

    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # e.g full_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserCreationView(CreateView):
    template_name = "form.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        middle_name = form.cleaned_data['middle_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        mobile_no = form.cleaned_data['mobile_no']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']

        user_data = {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "middle_name": middle_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "mobile_no": mobile_no,
            "email": email
        }

        if user_type == 'super-user':
            user = User.objects.create_super_user(username, password, **user_data)
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_staff_user(username, password, **user_data)

        form.instance.user = user
        form.instance.is_active = True
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Questions are:-

1. As far as i tried to debug, it could be the reason that `create_staff_user` and `create_super_user` functions have already created a row in database and now `form.save()` is also trying to insert the row again. (not sure)
2. do i need to do `form.save()` as i found that `super().form_valid(form)` also have implemented form saving function within it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you should only call save once, but you are calling it twice

```
form.save() # this line saves it to the database
super().form_valid(form) # and this line does that too
```

so after calling form.save() return response. 
update, your code to

```
class UserCreationView(CreateView):
    template_name = "form.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = "/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        middle_name = form.cleaned_data['middle_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        mobile_no = form.cleaned_data['mobile_no']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']

        user_data = {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "middle_name": middle_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "mobile_no": mobile_no,
            "email": email
        }

        if user_type == 'super-user':
            user = User.objects.create_super_user(username, password, **user_data)
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_staff_user(username, password, **user_data)

        form.instance.user = user
        form.instance.is_active = True
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

mobile number should be unique for every user

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser',)

    def clean_mobile_no(self):
        mobile_number = self.cleaned_data.get('mobile_no')
        user = User.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_number)
        if user:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "mobile no is taken"
                )
        return mobile_number
```

Comment: i know that. this code actually stores the row on database but it doesn't redirect to success url. it simply returns error

Comment: I have added detail description, you should call .save() only once

Comment: i tried this but it is simply not working. data is saved on the table but it throws Unique constraint error on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as for your first question, it could be the problem. I guess before you created a custom User model, you makes migrations and pushed them to your database. So, that is the part where Django also creates its own User model, with all the available columns and attributes. I would suggest to **DELETE** your currently Users table, and run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

As for your second question, the best practice and advice that I could give you is to **first** add an if clause, to check if the form data are valid, and **then** save the form and post the data. Although my advice does not really relate to your question, the point is to always validate the form's data and after you retrieve them, save the form (post the data).

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) it says that the `FormView` class on success will redirect the user and on error, it will redisplay the form. However, the `CreateView` will only display the errors and save the object, it will not redirect to anything. Although with the `CreateView` you can automatically save the form and its data, it will not redirect the user. I suggest you using the `FormView` class that will show if there any errors and will redirect the user on success, but be careful and save the form data at the end of the **POST** function.

I hope that helps! Please let me know if there is anything else I can help you with.

Comment: the form data is actually saved on database. it simply won't redirect me to the success url. rather it would throw Unique constraint error.

Comment: Why do not you go with Django's class-based view: FormView?